Backup and Restore Procedures for BACnet Secure Connect
How should the Backup and Restore procedure for BACnet Secure Connect be handled? Our IUT does not back up the certificates/keys used for BACnet Secure Connect. The reason is that copying or moving private keys increases the risk of them being intercepted or accessed by unauthorized individuals.
Would it be expected for the IUT to back up the BACnet files (in this case, the certificates/keys) and be able to restore them on another device? Additionally, there is a related issue where Network Port Objects (Secure Connect link) are not being backed up. Without having the certificates/files for the end user, it does not make sense to merely back up and restore the network port instances alone. Moreover, network port objects are created dynamically based on active data-links, so in our IUT, we are not performing backup/restore of network port objects.
Should the certificate files and the Network Port Objects (Secure Connect link) be backed up and restored? If so, how should this be done?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I personally think you're question might not be targeted enough / too many distracting facets to consider.  I think it might come down to your specific environment and therefore the feasible options that are available, but I imagine that you bootstrap/initialise things by reading the certs from a file, so why not a back-up of that file stored within the same location, and/or transported somewhere else more safe & central.
